# Linux Mplayer Instead of flash any distro/browser

Tags: linux, opera, flash-player, mplayer, chromium

The thing is that flash sucks for linux on 64-bit, performance vice. Due to this I actually download every clip to a temp folder and play the file while it's being downloaded with mplayer. This works really nice. Flash is not to play a video. Does there exist a plugin for this for any browser? I tried google, but I can't find the right words to search for.

Edit: I did find a plugin for playing wmp things, that is not what I'm asking for!

Comment: I run 64bit Ubuntu (Karmic and Lucid) and haven't had any problems using the 64bit flash, it's a bit tricky to get installed except that now there is a PPA to get it... http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2009/12/64bit-flash-ppa.html

works great for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not terribly clear, but if you want to use Mplayer as a plugin for your browser, you can use mplayerplugin, http://mplayerplug-in.sourceforge.net/ . It lets you use mplayer as a plugin inside Firefox.

Comment: That is the plugin for wmp things. It does not support playing flv files, or maybe it can be modified to do so. I'm going to contact them and ask around.

Comment: @data_jepp: Ah, I see the problem. I believe the reason is that flv files are not served directly, rather the web page will serve a Flash applet, which in turn loads the video. So a plugin would probably need to figure out which video the Flash applet is loading to then load the video for itself. Might be tricky...